# Wrong Implementation of LinkedList

Tags: python, class, linked-list, temporary

I am having trouble with the following code segment. I can't really figure out why it doesn't work, any help is appreciated. It's a very very simple mistake that I do not understand:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val = 0, next_node = None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next_node

    def add_node(self, new_val):
        temp = self
        self.val = new_val
        self.next = temp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    u = Node(1)
    u.add_node(5)
    print(u.next.val)
```

Prints 5 and it keeps printing 5 if you write `u.next.next.next.val`, what I want is `u.val = 5` , `u.next.val = 1` and `u.next.next = None`

Comment: Why are you pointing `self.next` to `self` (indirectly via `temp`)? This is circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to instantiate a new `Node` in `add_node`, and then set it as `next` of `self`.

Comment: Or pass `Node(5)` into the `add_node()` function, which might make more sense than passing the value 5.

Comment: Would this add the new node to the beginning of the list or to the end?

Comment: The new node would be at the end. If you need it before, you'd have to set its `next` to `self`, and then return it to keep track of the list's head.

Comment: Is there no way do to it without returning? Say, I want the add_node method to work under the hood.

Comment: As explained in details in the other answer's feed, you'd have to keep track of the `previous` node in another attribute. Then, if you don't want other objects or evemt a variable to hold the head node, you could iterate over `previous`es until you get to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new node, you never check if you are in the middle of the linked list, you simply change the current nodes  value and let if reference itself as next one (=> circular self pointing list). That does not make any sense.

You would instead neeed to:

- create a new node, set its value and set its `next_node` to your own `self.next`
- then set your `self.next` to the new node

---

```
def add_node(self, new_val):
    # self.next is either None or the remainder of your linked list
    new_node = Node(new_val, self.next)
    # insert as next node of yourself
    self.next = new_node
```

Comment: This does it, but the order is messed up. I would like to add the new node always to the beginning of the LinkedList

Comment: Then you need to store the beginning of the list somewhere - you have no way to get to the start from somewhere in between because it is a single linked list, not a double linked list where you also would have a self.prev pointing to the element before. A method `add_node` on a `Node(..)` instance that adds a new node somewhere else makes no sense - you may want to have a NodeList() class than holds the first element as self.first and a add_node() in that to reset self.-first to a new value and the new values self.next is set to what was in NodeList.first before.

Comment: the `add_node` at Node() level adds a new Node _after_ the Node it is called on wich makes sense.